# SSIS Flat FIle to OLE DB Destination Optimisation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

Relatively new to SSIS but I have built a package to load several grouped flat files (from a Progress data dump) into appropriate SQL staging tables. Each of the flat file groups represent the source logical table and exist as multiple flat files of the same table name with an int increment appended (e.g. matdb-1,matdb-2,etc). Each flat file holds delimited data with a maximum of 500,000 rows.

I have Foreach Loop Containers with a Data Flow Task containing a Flat File Source to OLE DB Destination using "Table or view - fast load", "Check Contstraints" unchecked, and then a File System Task to move the processed file to archive.

The largest table (currently 25.2 million rows) takes on average 6.5-7 minutes per file to process and I want to get that down, preferably by at least half. The destination table consists of 2 int columns, 30 varchar(max) columns, 6 varchar(100) columns and 1 varchar(18) column.

I have read, tried and tested a few article suggestions for amending the DefaultBufferMaxRows/DefaultBufferSize, setting the AutoAdjustBufferSize to True and amending the "Rows per batch"/"Maximum insert commit size" in the OLE DB Destination editor as means of improving performance from the defaults, but everything I have tried has only increased the processing time and I'm at a loss trying to find a more efficient solution.

Any and all questions/suggestions welcome and I will try to respond appropriately. Thanks.

Comment: Does your table contain constraints, keys or indexes? Are you using fast load when inserting? Do you really need varchar max?

Comment: There are no constraints and a Non-Clustered Index which I have disabled during the load procedure. Fast load is in use. The Column widths have been determined by the source so unfortunately I am unable to change them.

Comment: did you try using `OPENROWSET` instead?, it would be very easy to produce incremental filenames within a loop

Comment: @avb I'm not looking to produce incremental filenames, the files are produced from the source system by a procedure which I have limited control over. The task I have is to create an efficient means to load the full data set to the staging area (eventually) nightly. The problem with the solution thus far is the procedural load time on the largest logical table.

Comment: I meant producing it for filenames for openrowset command, I just tested it for a file with 4.5M rows with 20 nvarchar columns and it took 24s to load to stage table...

Comment: I think it is also important for the files not to be located on remote location from your sql server

Comment: What is the process waiting on: network, disk, cpu, or memory? When you are testing the package run times - how are you running them?

Comment: @avb openrowset isnt something I have considered or tried. I will do some reading, test and come back to you. The Flat Files are held on the remote server from which they are produced.

Comment: @billinkc this is what I'm unsure of how to determine and would like to analyse. I'm running SSIS from VS2017 local install and currently examining the Execution Results to determine the process times of each file load.

Comment: I think copying them locally to sql server would help..

Comment: When an SSIS package is run from Visual Studio, it's run in the context of the debugger which has a surprisingly heavy drag on processing. Deploy your packages to a server and execute it from there (command line, SQL Agent, SSIS catalog procedure) and that will give you a truer baseline for performance

Answer (score -1):

Just in case speeding up with SSIS did not succeed... here's my sql approach:

```
declare @i int = 1;
declare @maxFileNo int = 6;

declare @filenamePattern nvarchar(99) = 'matdb-';
declare @sqlPattern nvarchar(999) = 'insert stageTable select * from OPENROWSET(BULK ''__fileName__'', formatfile = ''formatFile.fmt'') a';
declare @sql nvarchar(999);

while @i <= @maxFileNo begin
    set @sql = REPLACE(@sqlPattern, '__fileName__', @filenamePattern + CAST(@i as nvarchar(2)));
    exec(@sql);
    set @i += 1;
end
```